# How to design table with header cells in the top row and first column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Here I am trying to achieve, To design a table with header cell in the top row and first column. Here is my simple design.
[image: here is my simple design]

I am getting some data in response on the basis of that I am showing data in respective cell and coloring the cell.

How can we design this type of table in bootsrap?
any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use TH in the correct places

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>MA/RCF</th>
          <th>100</th>
          <th>156</th>
          <th>180</th>
          <th>856</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>0</th>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>100</th>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```